# RecordSetDestination SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

What is the major use of recordset destination in SSIS?I heard that it is an in-memory,so the variable which is holding the data is it in raw format?  Can someone explain the explain me the real time project use of Recordset destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recordset destination can be used for just about anything you can think of.  Some common uses I hear is to use the recordset in a foreach loop.  Say you want to export several "categories" from a transaction table.  Perhaps you get a recordset of the categories that exist and then call a new dataflow to export that category as it's own file.  Or perhaps date ranges, months, etc.

One way I use it is in a script task to perform an action on the data that SSIS cannot do natively.  I was using a script component but this particular task ran into a concurrency issue.  So by dumping to a recordset I was able to use the recordset in a script task to do the logic in a manner to avoid that issue.

Another script task use is to build and send HTML emails.

I suppose a use for it might be when you have 1 data flow to get 1 record set then do a bunch of non dataflow tasks and then use that as a source in another data flow task, but that is not something I have ever done.